# How to connect anti-static wrist straps without a desktop PC case

Tags: laptop-repair, repair, static-discharge, esd

I looked up tutorials on how to use an anti-static wrist strap and they all seem to tell me to connect it to a desktop PC case while having the PC turned off but plugged in.

I need to open up my laptop but I have no desktop PC or PC case. What should I do for grounding?

Comment: I am not advocating what I am about to tell you but I have been building machines since the 80s.  I have also repaired countless laptops to include motherboard replacement.  I have never worn said wrist strap.  I have fried ZERO machines.  Sure, you are safer using one.. but the chances are very VERY low of creating a static discharge that will damage modern hardware.  To answer your question, once you open up the laptop look for a metal frame inside to clip it to.

Comment: You can purchase a mains plug which will allow you to connect the strap to. And I _have_ fried systems without taking proper anti-static precautions, as have many others.

Comment: @Bib do you mean i just clip it to the earth wire of a power socket? Is it even safe? I know the earth wire is connected to the ground but intuitively it just feels sus… what about in the case of a surge? I’m sort of looking for options that are less scary

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas does the metal frame need to be in contact of something else in order for the discharge to leave both me and the metal frame? Can i use uncoated household objects made of metal such as a stainless steel bowl

Comment: @Bib or do you mean to clip it to the plug of an electric appliance that’s not plugged in? Does the appliance itself need to be in contact of something else that lets the discharge leave?

Comment: @Egoless Just do a search for `anti-static mains plug` You connect a wrist strap directly to it.

Comment: @Egoless, find me a metal internal laptop frame that doesn't have things grounded to it.

Comment: Look.. I guess I am lucky/magic with 1000s (yes 1000s) of pc builds and repairs and never using one.  How does one KNOW that static electricity is why the component no longer works?  Also, see [this](https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/is-an-anti-static-wrist-strap-really-needed.1688257/).  Simply ground yourself out briefly beforehand.. and don't walk in place on the carpet or rake baloons on your head :P

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas but if the metal frame is to be grounded via a connection to something does the laptop need to be plugged in and turned off? But it’s opened up for repair

Comment: @Bib okay, I’ll go have a look. Thanks